# Is there a library for writing html from Java?

Tags: java, html

Trying to write html in Java I keep finding myself writing methods like

```
public String makeHyperlink(String hyperlink, String text)
{
    return "<a href=\""+ hyperlink +"\">" + text + "</a>\n";
}
```

to make it more palatable.

Does anyone know of  library that already exists for such stuff, I did look but could not find anything.

Comment: @Reimeus are you sure seems to be a library for reading html not writing

Comment: In your question the context matters. I mean, what are you trying to do exactly? Jsoup is one way, velocity templates is another, jsp for something else. Every one of these could go a long way depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: I was just looking for a POJO library that provided methods like the one listed above

Comment: Jsoup would do then. Although you don't need to parse html, it provides convenient classes that could do the trick. Check `Element` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're searching for a library capable of manipulating html documents, [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) is pretty useful! But depending on what you have to do you can use a vast set of tools and/or framework, such as jetty or spring, where you can write dynamic jstl pages which output html documents.

Comment: A useful library that I hadn't heard of so marking this as accepted. But it doesn't offer much in the way of help for writing elements so I'll ust continue creating my own set